# What if a particle with energy E falls in a potential well?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy

Imagine we have a particle with an energy $E$ that can be any value in a continuous subset of $\mathbb{R}^+$. What would happen if this particle, in a way or an other, fell in a potential well where the energy spectrum is a discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}$ ? Is it simply impossible ? Will-it get away from the well or release (gain ?) some energy to reach the nearest $E_n$ authorized in the well ?

Edit after the comment: the energy of the particle. I mean, the Hamiltonian spectrum is discrete in the well, but what if before it enters it, the energy in not an eigenvalue ? (i'm aware that it's not really clear but i do my best :/)

Comment: welcome to Physics Stack Exchange, could you clarify your question, as in, what types of energy you mean, and perhaps a diagram to clarify further

Comment: Maybe related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/526654/201709

Answer (score 1):

If the particle can enter the well, it means its energy is bigger than the energy depth of the well, which must be finite. Therefore, the spectrum of energies in the well is made of a discrete part (for low energies) and a continuous part (above a certain threshold, which is by definition the depth of the well). As a consequence, the incoming particle energy belongs to the continuous part, and it is automatically an eigenvalue of the Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the energy must be bigger than the potential well ?
If the energy is greater than $0$ (stated that the bottom value is $-V0$), I agree, it will be in the continuous part of the hamiltonian. But if not, it can go through and enter the well, the same thing happens with the tunnel effect. Therefore, what would happen to it's energy ? (The probability it has $E=E_n$ is zero...)

Comment: If the particle was not originally in the well, it means that its energy is bigger than the asymptotic energy of the well. You are right when you say that the particle will ultimately go through the well. It will never become a bound state (as long as the energy remains the same, which is the case unless you have some dissipation mechanism).